# After logging in to ubuntu 20.04.1, ubuntu gets stuck on a purple screen, but when I take my wifi card out, I can log in successfully

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04

So like title says, ubuntu gets stuck on a purple screen after logging in, but when I take out my wifi card, it allows me to log in. Does anyone know a possible fix for this?
I could log in before with my wifi card installed, but when I shut down it gives me a long continuous list of errors about pcie bus.
If anyone can help me, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.